# Bar graphs with error bars, colour and names for legend

Tags: r

I have a variable X and Y variable. I am working to produce graph with error bars, different colours and factor names with ggplot but some how stuck. I need to have the Lambing to appear from 1,2, 3 with names e.g 1=Inside. Also want to include error bars plus bars to have 3 distinct different colours.

Here is my code and sample of data.

```
ggplot(na.omit(orf), aes(x = factor(Lambing), 
  y = Cases2012,fill=Lambing)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position="dodge", width=.6,)+ 
 xlab("Lambing") + ylab("Number of cases") +  
ggtitle("Orf cases in relation to lambing")
```

Here is the data sample:

```
Lambing Cases2012
1   80
1   0
1   8
2   73
1   0
1   26
2   0
1   45
2   0
1   22
1   0
3   30
3   0
1   6
1   539
3   100
1   0
3   20
1   0
1   10
1   0
1   70
3   0
2   35
1   2100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems/questions here.

- are you sure the Y-values are what you want (i.e. is `stat="identity"` really correct)?  If you add `alpha=0.2` to `geom_bar` you'll see that all the different values are overplotted at the same X location.  Would you rather compute the mean or sum of values within a category, e.g. `stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="bar")` (dodging doesn't really seem to be doing anything here)?
- how do you want to compute error ranges?  Below I've used bootstrap CIs
- the bar numbers seem redundant (but I may have misunderstood your request: rereading it, I think `factor(Lambing)` does what you want ... if this is the case, just delete/comment out the `geom_text()` layer below)

**edit**:

- the easiest way to change legend/x-axis labels is to change the levels of the factor, i.e. `levels(orf$Lambing) <- c("inside","partly","outside")` (be careful with this -- it's up to you to get them in the right order!)
- the easiest way to adjust the error bar calculation is to use one of the alternatives to `?mean_cl_boot`: these are best documented via `help("smean.cl.boot",package="Hmisc")`. The `ggplot2` package provides wrappers, e.g. `smean.cl.boot` (`Hmisc`) -> `mean_cl_boot` (`ggplot2`), e.g.:

  - `mean_cl_normal`: CIs assuming Normality (i.e. based on standard error/Student t)
  - `mean_cl_boot`: nonparametric bootstrap-based CIs
  - `median_hilow`: median and quantiles

```
library("ggplot2")
## compute label positions
orfsum <- aggregate(Cases2012~Lambing,function(x) mean(x)/2,data=orf)
ggplot(na.omit(orf), aes(x = factor(Lambing), y = Cases2012,
    ## specify fill and line colours as categorical labels
    fill=factor(Lambing),colour=factor(Lambing))) +
    ## bars at mean height (alpha=0.5 so we can see lower error range)
    stat_summary(fun.y="mean",geom="bar",alpha=0.5)+
        ## bootstrap-based whiskers
        stat_summary(fun.data="mean_cl_boot",geom="linerange")+
           geom_text(data=orfsum,aes(label=Lambing),colour="black")+
       labs(x="Lambing",y="Number of cases",
             title="Mean orf cases related to lambing")
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks.  Exactly what I was looking for. How do I fill in names for factor(lambing) for example: 1=inside, 2=partly, 3=outside. Also how else can I compute error ranges apart from using bootstrap CIs

Comment: Thanks, very helpful indeed

Comment: How about if I wanted to try box plot. I tried this code but get error: ggplot(data=orf, aes(x=Lambing, y=Cases2012, fill=Lambing)) + geom_boxplot()

Comment: `ggplot(na.omit(orf), aes(x = factor(Lambing), y = Cases2012, fill=factor(Lambing),colour=factor(Lambing))) + geom_boxplot()` works for me.  When you get errors you should post them ...

Comment: Thanks, worked fine. think error was because I had missed some bits in the coding.